# How do I fetch data from the server using Props from React Router & Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, antd

I am using React Router, Redux, Redux Sagas, antd in my project.
My main goal is to click on a cell from the table of items, go to the next page, which is Details page for that item, and fetch details from server using ID that I pass in from the Link. It is not working right now.
I have a component, component A, which has column like this:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'ID',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    key: 'id',
    render: (id: number) => <Link to={{ pathname: `/pages/my-page/${id}`, state: {id}}}>{id}</Link>,
  },
```

It goes to the next component, Component B, with the param id passed in. Now, I want to use that id to do further fetching of details for that particular item, using redux and redux saga and render it on the next page, Component B, which I do using constructor. I tried using this below code in componentDidMount() as well, but that doesn't work either.

```
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    const {onDetailsSearch, state} = props;
    const {router} = state;
    const {location} = router;
    const {state: newState}: {state: any} = location;
    onDetailsSearch({id: (newState || {}).id});
  }
```

This is what is in the reducer:

```
import {DetailsState} from 'state/'
import actions, {DetailsAction} from './actions'

export interface DetailsState {
  loading: boolean
  id: number
  items: Details[]
}

const initialState: DetailsState = {
  loading: false,
  id: 0,
  items: [],
}

export default function DetailsReducer(state: DetailsState = initialState, action: DetailsAction): DetailsState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.SET_STATE:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This is the Redux saga code:

```
import {all, call, put, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import getDetails from "services/getDetails";
import actions from './actions'

type Params = {
  type: typeof actions.LOAD_DETAILS
  payload: object
}

export function* LOAD_DETAILS({ payload }: Params) {
  yield put({
    type: 'details/SET_STATE',
    payload: {
      loading: true,
    },
  })
  const { response, error } = yield call(getDetails, payload)
  console.log('response:', response);
  if (!error) {
    yield put({
      type: 'details/SET_STATE',
      payload: {
        details: response.data,
      },
    })
  }
  else {
    // TODO: handle error
  }
  yield put({
    type: 'details/SET_STATE',
    payload: {
      loading: false,
    },
  })
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(actions.LOAD_DETAILS, LOAD_DETAILS),
  ])
}
```

This is how I call the dispatch function onDetailsSearch, which in turn should call the saga and set the results in the redux store.

But its not doing that. What is wrong here?

Comment: Could you provide the redux, redux-saga code as well, also you should do data fetching inside the componentDidMount, not the constructor.

Comment: I wrote the code inside componentDidMount earlier. But didn't seem to work.
Updated the original post @jean182

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. I have actions stored as constants in a actionConstants.ts file.

The action constant for this particular action was `'details/LOAD_DETAILS'`, and the action string in dispatch I was using was `'LOAD_DETAILS'`